# How do I copy a one-dimensional array to part of another two-dimensional array, and vice-versa?

Tags: c, arrays

Basically, I have three arrays, CQueue (2D-array), PQueue (2D-array, the same number of arrays as the CQueue, but with each array containing twice as many values) and CC (standard array which is as long as an array in the CQueue). What I *want* to achieve is taking a specific array in the CQueue, copying it so that CC reads exactly the same as CQueue, and so that the first half of the equivalent array in the PQueue also reads the same.

I've been advised to use memcpy by a friend, which seemed fine but hasn't fixed the problem. I don't know whether the problem lies within me potentially using memcpy incorrectly or whether there's another issue at hand. Following is a simplified version of the relevant part of the code.

```
int (main)
{
  int CQueue[numberOfArrays][halfSize]
  int PQueue[numberOfArrays][size]
  int CC[halfSize]

  for (i = 0; i < numberOfArrays]; i++)
  {
    memcpy (CC, CQueue[i], halfSize)
    memcpy (PQueue[i], CQueue[i], size)
  }
}
```

Any help offered would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: the last argument in `memcpy` is the number of bytes to copy, so you should be copying `X*sizeof(int)`, not just `X`

Comment: You want a specific array or all of them? You're iterating over all of them, which isn't what you described, and also wasteful, since `CC` ends up being written over many times and only the last value will remain.

Comment: What I posted was a simplified version only showing the relevant part of the problem - I'm doing a lot more stuff inside that for loop, but nothing that should have affect on this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third argument to `memcpy` is the amount to copy *in characters* (i.e. bytes on most platforms).  So you need to do something like:

```
memcpy(CC, CQueue[i], halfSize*sizeof(*CC));
```

Answer (score 0):

`memcpy` copies bytes, not ints. You need to multiply the number of elements to copy by the size of each such element

```
memcpy(dst, src, elems * sizeof elem);
```

in your code

```
    memcpy (CC, CQueue[i], halfSize * sizeof *CC);
    memcpy (PQueue[i], CQueue[i], size * sizeof *PQueue[i]);
```